# how to make include element in my own XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, include

I have writen my own xml schema and one large xml file that is an instance of that schema. Now I would like to define include element in my xsd so that xml file can be made out of several smaller units. How do I do that?
For example in my file I have

`<item>1</item>`
`<item>2</item>`
`<item>3</item>`
`<include src='foo.xml'>`

and foo.xml has content:

`<item>4</item>`
`<item>5</item>`
`<item>6</item>`

and together they make needed set of values. 
Thanks ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

XML is just a data representation and structuring format.  If you need "include"-type functionality, you have to implement that in whatever you are using to process the XML.  Maybe if you provided a little more context on what you're trying to accomplish (by editing your original question) we could help you.